# hyperlink is not enabled with my PDFView pdfView;

Tags: java, android, android-layout

**I had created my first application with android studio for my pdf courses but the hyperlink between beamer pages in my file "17-nor.pdf"are not activated**

```
 PDFView pdfView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pdfView=(PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
    pdfView.fromAsset("17-nor.pdf").load();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Firs**t of all, make sure you added your pdf file to assets directory in your project
**Then**, I've never used this library before but I see in the example that there are several methods included to load a pdf

```
pdfView.fromAsset(pdfName)
    .pages(0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3)
    .defaultPage(1)
    .showMinimap(false)
    .enableSwipe(true)
    .onDraw(onDrawListener)
    .onLoad(onLoadCompleteListener)
    .onPageChange(onPageChangeListener)
    .load();
```

> `pages` is optional, it allows you to filter and order the pages of the
>   PDF as you need `onDraw` is also optional, and allows you to draw
>   something on a provided canvas, above the current page

This says only pages and onDraw optional, the docs don't mention that the other methods ar optional too. Try adding them

Comment: my probleme is not solved I'm trying to use latest versions of PDF-VIEWRS Version 3.0.0 introduced support for links but it dosn't work for me gradle can not synchronize it, can you help me please??

Comment: Post your gradle file and the error if you get it in logs

Comment: I solved my problem, at first compiling my project I got the following error:

Comment: I solved my problem, at first compiling my project I got the following error:                      error: cannot find symbol class PDFVIEW                                       execution failed for task':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'                                  >Compilation failed: see the compiler error output for details. i had press to alt+entree and import the class name PDFVIEW in MAinActivity.java      I recompiled a Project, and now everything went well thanks you so much